# How do i run different sass sub tasks depending on what watched files have changed?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Is there any way to watch different sets of files and run different tasks based on which set have changed?

The reason I ask is because i am working with several separate sites for different countries (UK,US, French, German). My core sass is in a UK folder, but there are separate French, German and US folders with sass overrides to the core css in.

My grunt file looks like so:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            files: ['../style/v4/sass/**/*.scss', '../../US/style/v4/sass/**/*.scss', '../../France/style/v4/sass/**/*.scss', '../../Germany/style/v4/sass/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass:uk'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            },
        },
        sass: {
            uk: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../style/v4/css/screen.css': '../style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            },
            us: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../../US/style/v4/css/screen.css': '../../US/style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            },
            fr: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../../France/style/v4/css/screen.css': '../../France/style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            },
            de: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../../Germany/style/v4/css/screen.css': '../../Germany/style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

So as you can see, at the moment when any of the core UK files or French, German, US files are changed they just run the **sass:uk** compilation task.

What i want to happen is if the uk files change then run all of the sass sub-tasks to compile the scss. If the France scss files change then run just the **sass:fr** task, if the US scss files change run just the **sass:us** task and so on.

How would i structure my gruntfile to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone was having the same issue, i solved it by setting up individual watching tasks for the different countries. Pretty obvious really:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            uk: {
                files: ['../style/v4/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            us: {
                files: ['../../US/style/v4/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:us'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            fr: {
                files: ['../../France/style/v4/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:fr'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            de: {
                files: ['../../Germany/style/v4/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:de'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            uk: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../style/v4/css/screen.css': '../style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            },
            us: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../../US/style/v4/css/screen.css': '../../US/style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            },
            fr: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../../France/style/v4/css/screen.css': '../../France/style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            },
            de: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: true,
                    compass: true
                },
                files: {'../../Germany/style/v4/css/screen.css': '../../Germany/style/v4/sass/screen.scss'}
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```